# Ionic: Adding platform gives error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, osx-yosemite

Having first Ionic encounter, I am setting the environment up for an Android app on OSX Yosemite. By running the command `sudo ionic platform android` I am getting following error:

```
Error: %s Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/myUser/hooks'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:761:18)
    at Object.setHooksPermission (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/hooks.js:116:24)
    at Object.IonicTask.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:51:13)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/cli.js:95:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Error happened { [Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/myUser/config.xml'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/Users/myUser/config.xml' }
Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/myUser/config.xml'
    at Error (native)
```

**Versions after running their upgrade**:

```
├── cordova@5.4.1 
└── ionic@1.7.12
```

Comment: Do you have the /Users/myUser/config.xml file?

Comment: @GuillermoMerino No. How do I generate it. I just installed Ionic. Haven't created project yet.

Comment: Try adding `add` as follows: `ionic platform add android`

Comment: @Volatil3 When you generate a new project (`ionic start YourAppName blank`), the `config.xml` file creates automatically.

Comment: @Volatil3, why sudo?

Comment: @GuillermoMerino you should make your comment as an Answer

Answer (score 2):

It should be this,

```
$ ionic platform add android
```

Also, you'd better not run command with `sudo` or you might face with troubles with permission some time later.

Comment: for OSX it is needed

Comment: The poster has probably made a typo, but this is not a solution, even i am getting this error for ionic platform remove ios

Answer (score 1):

please go to myApp folder

then run the command :

ionic platform add android

Comment: exactly you need to execute the command into the application folder

Answer (score 0):

My android platform was corrupt, after removing it and adding it properly, the issue got solved

Answer (score 0):

go to ionic app folder where your config.xml file exists.and then execute this command.

`$ cd Myapp`
where folder structure should look like this

`$Myapp -> ls`

`$Myapp -> bower.json  gulpfile.js  ionic.project  platforms  README.md  scss
config.xml  hooks        package.json   plugins    resources  www`

`$Myapp -> ionic platform add android`